# Get TCP global settings of the remote PC

Tags: c#, tcp, remote-access

I'm trying to get TCP settings of the remote PC. It's easy to get local TCP settings by running `netsh int tcp show global`

I've tried to use -r switch and specify remote machine name, but `show global` command is not available under `int tcp` context, thought `show global` works fine under `int ip` context.

I've also tried to use `psexec` to execute `netsh` on remote PC, but only first line of the output is returned, no matter what command you run. Some people have the same issue, and looks like all of them just gave up. Here is my code snippet:

```
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;            
    p.StartInfo.FileName = "PsExec.exe";
    p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\remotemachine -u DOMAIN\username -p pwd netsh int tcp show global";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();

    string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    string errormessage = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

    Console.WriteLine("Standard Output:\n" + output + "Standard Error:\n" + errormessage);
```

Is ther any way to get TCP paramters through WMI maybe or any other way to do it with C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by writing `psexec` output to the file:

```
psexec \\remotemachine -u DOMAIN\username -p pwd netsh int tcp show global > c:\output.log
```